# R shiny - correct use of an input variable, seems like a scope error

Tags: r, shiny

I think I have a problem with the scope of input$variable.  Following is the code description.

In my ui.R file I have a selectInput that defines the value taken by input$variable in my server.R file.  The selectInput is as follows:

```
selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
     c("Handling of Complaints" = "complaints",
       "Does not allow special privileges" = "privileges",
       "Opportunity to Learn" = "learning",
       "Raises based on Performance" = "raises",
       "Too Critical" = "critical",
       "Advancement" = "advance")),
```

In my server.R file I have a renderUI that uses this input$variable inside a with and inside a qplot as follows:

```
grid <- with(attitudeData, expand.grid(
     xgrid = seq(min(input$variable), max(input$variable), length = dim(attitudeData)[1]),
     ygrid = levels(sex)
    ))

ggattitude <- qplot(x=input$variable, y=rating, 
      data=attitudeData, color=sex) + geom_line(data=grid)
```

attitudeData is the dataframe with variables (aka features or predictors) with names as defined in the selectInput.

If I use any of the variable names, say complaints, directly in the code it works and my plot is generated the way I want for that variable.  But with **input$variable** I can't get it to work.  This is why I think the problem has to do with the scope of **input$variable**.

Any help would be appreciated.

Following is the error I get from shiny which isn't very helpful to me.

```
Error in seq.default(min(input$variable), max(input$variable), length = dim(attitudeData)[1]) :  'from' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite
```

If I replace input$variable with complaints in the with, the error for the use in qplot is as follows:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'complaints' not found
```

Thanks in advance for any help I get.

Answer (score 0):

You can add print statements to clarify what R sees as input.  In your server file:

```
grid <- with(attitudeData, expand.grid(
     print(input$variable) 
     xgrid = seq(min(input$variable), max(input$variable), length = dim(attitudeData)[1]),
     ygrid = levels(sex)
    ))

ggattitude <- qplot(x=input$variable, y=rating, 
      data=attitudeData, color=sex) + geom_line(data=grid)
```

This output will be printed to the R console.  I have a feeling that your input isn't rendering as "complaints".

Answer (score 0):

What should `min("complaints")` return? So you are giving string as argument to function `min()` it is different from `min(complaints)` if that is what you want.

Or is there some other problem like:

> xgrid = seq(min(input$variable), max(input$variable), length = dim(attitudeData)[1])

I am wondering if you really try to do:

```
xgrid = seq(min(attitudeData[input$variable]), max(attitudeData[input$variable]), length = dim(attitudeData)[1])
```